# Flexslider Syncing thumbnails/sliding thumbnails broken

Tags: jquery, slider, synchronization, flexslider

Synching thumbnails in flexslider version 2.0 onwards is broken.

Every thumbnail slide are off by one - the highlighted pager image is one more than the slide displayed in the main slider. The off-by-one is not present in 2.2.0.

BUT, the sliding pager in 2.2.0 is broken on looping. If the final slide is clicked next, the pager doesn't loop back to 0, but the main slider does show 0. Clicking next show 1, but still the pager doesn't loop. When 1 is clicked to go to 2, the sliding pager finally loops back.

Anyone knows this issue.... I tried many things in jquery.flexslider.js but not succeeded.

Comment: Can you add a js fiddle of what issue you are getting?

Comment: I have solved this issue using following fix. Please refer below link https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/1140